# How can I get a list of all the mesh objects names in a scene?

Tags: modeling, python, scripting, export, import

im trying to do a batch import/export in blender

and to run my code i need the name of the mesh, so i just print all the names in a list

and run:

```
import bpy
import os

# dict for mesh:object[]
mesh_objects = {}

# create dict with meshes
for m in bpy.data.meshes:
    mesh_objects[m.name] = []

# attach objects to dict keys
for o in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    # only for meshes
    if o.type == 'MESH':
        # if this mesh exists in the dict
        if o.data.name in mesh_objects:
            # object name mapped to mesh
            mesh_objects[o.data.name].append(o.name)

print(mesh_objects)


x = 0

    While x < 99999:
        print(mesh_objects[x])
        #here i do my code
        x += 1
```

but it gives me this error everytime, even though it works inside normal ide's:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\m8\Documents\untitled.blend\Text.py", line 24, in <module>
KeyError: 0
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console
```

thanks for all the help!

Comment: Item X is not part of the dict hence the 'KeyError': https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46024562/how-do-i-avoid-keyerror-when-working-with-dictionaries

Comment: To follow up on what `brockmann` said: I think the problem is, when you try to print, you're treating `mesh_objects` as if it is a list, but it is a dictionary, with list-valued values. Its keys are string names corresponding object names, and the error message `KeyError: 0` is just telling you that you never added a key-value pair to the dictionary where the key was `0` -- which makes sense, since all of your keys are string names of objects. If you switch from the `While x < 9999` and iterating over `x` to something like `for k, v in mesh_objects.items()`, that will iterate properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**All meshes in scene.**

*Some Common  methods seen in many answers, will look for links, but none  AFAICT ask this specifically*

**Using Sets.**

To get a list of all meshes in scene can use a set, which will keep the number of each to one.

Set of all meshes in a scene

```
meshes = set(o.data for o in scene.objects if o.type == 'MESH')
```

or by name

```
meshes = set(o.data.name for o in scene.objects if o.type == 'MESH')
```

**Default Dictionary.**

To make a lookup table, mesh --> the objects in the scene it is linked to I find `collections.defaultdict` the way to go.  Consult the docs. In example below, if not previously set the value of any key will be a new empty list object.

```
from collections import defaultdict
dd = defaultdict(list)
print(dd["foo"])
```

Here is an example using mesh object as key, and appending the object.

```
import bpy
from bpy import context
from collections import defaultdict

meshes = defaultdict(list)

scene = context.scene
for o in scene.objects:
    if o.type != 'MESH':
        continue
    meshes[o.data].append(o)
    
for me, obs in meshes.items():
    print(me.name, [o.name for o in obs])
```

For example to loop the dictionary, process the mesh, and each scene object using the mesh in importer / exporter

```
for me, obs in meshes.items():
    # Process (Export) the mesh export
    print("Exporting Mesh", me.name)

    # Export Each scene object using this mesh
    for obj in obs:
        print("\tExport Object", obj.name)
        print("\tdimensions: ", obj.dimensions[:])
```

or use name as dictionary key, and list item then

```
    meshes[o.data.name].append(o.name)
```

in which case, names of  meshes in scene is `meshes.keys()`

Comment: thanks! @batFINGER