# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'dimensions'

Tags: modeling, python, objects, dimensions, obj

i have a bpy code for taking in objects and exporting their bounding box as a .obj, but i keep getting this error whenever i try to copy the dimensions of the mesh:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\m8\Documents\untitled.blend\Text.py", line 52, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'dimensions'
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console
```

my code:

```
import bpy
import os

# dict for mesh:object[]
mesh_objects = {}

# create dict with meshes
for m in bpy.data.meshes:
    mesh_objects[m.name] = []

# attach objects to dict keys
for o in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    # only for meshes
    if o.type == 'MESH':
        # if this mesh exists in the dict
        if o.data.name in mesh_objects:
            # object name mapped to mesh
            mesh_objects[o.data.name].append(o.name)

#print(mesh_objects)

mesh_list = []

for f in mesh_objects:
    mesh_list.append(f)


x = 0    

the_object = mesh_list[x]
#print(the_object)
  

#print(mesh_list)



while x < len(mesh_list):
    pp = mesh_objects.get(the_object)
    print(pp)
    selected = pp
    print(selected)
    for obj in selected:
        #ensure origin is centered on bounding box center
        bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_GEOMETRY', center='BOUNDS')
        #create a cube for the bounding box
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
        #our new cube is now the active object, so we can keep track of it in a variable:
        bound_box = bpy.context.active_object
         
        #copy transforms
        bound_box.dimensions = obj.dimensions
        bound_box.location = obj.location
        bound_box.rotation_euler = obj.rotation_euler
          
          
        bpy.data.objects[selected].select_set(True)
          
        lend_file_path = 'C:\\Users\\m8\\Desktop\\san andrejo\\stuff\\bb\\bb'
        directory = os.path.dirname(blend_file_path)
        target_file = os.path.join(directory, selected + '.obj')
          
        bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(filepath=target_file)
        x += 1
```

i know that the problem is that it's supposed to be a float, but i have no idea how to fix it,
its reffering to 'obj' but i have no values named obj and you cannot assing `float(obj)` to the call

so im hoping someone can help

thanks!

Comment: Answered your [prior question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/237163/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-mesh-objects-names-in-a-scene) based on question's title, not question's content, which like here is  a python runtime error.  (_Was searching for a duplicate to shut it down (close the question)_) An object _eg_ `bpy.data.objects["Foo"]` has a dimensions attribute, a string (`str`) _eg_ "Foo" does not.  Strongly recommend pecking about in python console, and searching online re how to decipher (in this case) an `AttributeError`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question. It is outside the scope of BSE to answer questions relating to  generic python script debugging.

Answer (score 1):

your "mesh_objects" are not objects, but just a list of strings.

you define this in this line:

```
mesh_objects[o.data.name].append(o.name)
```

and in this line:

```
bound_box.dimensions = obj.dimensions
```

the error happens, because obj is just a string, not an object.

You should use commands like "print (obj)" to see what's going on and to know what's in your variable.

to correct this error you have to fill in the objects in the list instead of just the names.

Like this:

```
mesh_objects[o.data.name].append(o)
```

Comment: `type(variable)` might be helpful in this case as well.

Comment: ooohhh.... ok, i understand the problem now, but how should i fix it? cause when i use the object from the dictionary instead of the list it gives me the same error

Comment: i updated my answer